# Possible range of correlation between two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I was given this question in a job interview and I wasn't sure how to answer it.

Suppose you have two random variables, $X,Y$.
Let us say that $X=1$ with probability $50\%$ and $0$ otherwise,
$Y=1$ with probability of $30\%$ and $0$ otherwise.

The first question was what is the range of probabilities for the event $X=1 ,Y=1$? The answer to that would be from $0\%$ to $30\%$, so this is not the focus of my question

The second question, which I was unsure of, is the following - what is the range of the **correlation** between both variables? The standard formula for correlation seemed quite unhelpful, especially since the question wasn't phrased like that with 0 and 1 (it was framed in the sense that $X$ or $Y$ occurred or did not occur)

Comment: It seems the answer to the first question is between 0% and 30%.

Comment: Indeed the first answer seems to be wrong. Consider:

$p(X=0,Y=0)=1/5$ ,

$p(X=0,Y=0)=3/10$ 

$p(X=1,Y=0)=1/2$ ,

$p(X=1,Y=1)=0$,

Comment: Yes, I messed up the answer in the first question when I wrote this down

Comment: @Michael This sounds like a fun interview! Mind if I ask which company it was for?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I'm not sure I can tell, but it was for a large hedge fund, for the position of entry level quant analyst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(X=1,Y=1)\leq \min \{P(X=1),P(Y=1)\}=0.3,$ we have $$P(X=1,Y=1)\in [0,0.3].$$ Further, since $X\sim Bern(0.5),Y\sim Bern(0.3),$ we know $E[XY]=P(X=1,Y=1)$ and

$$E[X]=0.5,E[Y]=0.3,Var(X)=0.5(1-0.5)=0.25,Var(Y)=0.3(1-0.3)=0.21.$$

Thus, $$\text{Corr(X,Y)}=\frac{E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{Var(x)Var(Y)}}=\frac{E[XY]-(0.5)(0.3)}{\sqrt{(0.25)(0.21)}}\\
\in \left[\frac{0-(0.5)(0.3)}{\sqrt{(0.25)(0.21)}},\frac{0.3-(0.5)(0.3)}{\sqrt{(0.25)(0.21)}}\right]\approx \left[-0.65,+0.65\right].$$

---

To see a concrete example where any value of this range can be realized, flip two coins in succession. The first coin is fair. If the first coin lands heads, the second coin that is used will be weighted with probability $p$ of landing heads. If the first coin lands tails, the second coin that is used will be weighted with probability $0.6-p$ of landing heads. Let $X,Y$ be indicators for coin 1, coin 2 respectively landing heads. This setup meets the assumptions of the problem, and since $0.6-p\geq 0\implies p\in [0,0.6],$ we have $$P(X=1,Y=1)=0.5p\in [0,0.3].$$

Answer (score 0):

Visualisation:

Take a line segment of length $1$.   Mark $0.50$ as the event $X=1$.  Place aside it another line segment of length $0.30$ to mark the event $Y=1$.  Slide it along the first segment to identify the possible range of the joint event's probability.

At a minimum, there is no overlap.  At a maximum, there is complete overlap (of the longer segment over the shorter).

Thus: $~0\leqslant\mathsf P(X{=}1,Y{=}1)\leqslant 0.30$

---

The formula for correlation is: $$\begin{align}\mathsf{Corr}(X,Y)&=\dfrac{\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)}{~\sqrt{\raise{2ex}~{\mathsf{Var}(X)~\mathsf{Var}(Y)}~}~}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)}{~\sqrt{\big(\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2\big)\,\big(\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2\big)~}~}\\[2ex]~\end{align}$$

Where $$\begin{align}\mathsf {E}(X)&=1~\mathsf P(X{=}1)+0~\mathsf P(X{=}0)\\ &=\mathsf P(X{=}1)\\\text{et cetera}\end{align}$$